# f2py does not return dimension(N,3) to python

Tags: python, f2py

I'm working with f2py and I'm quite stuck. I have a function in fortran:

```
!f90 
subroutine f( !args
implicit none; 

double precision, dimension(N, 3):: fMatrix; 
!f2py double precision, dimension(N,3), intent(out, c) :: fMatrix  
!Stuff happens here

end subroutine force
```

I've used

```
f2py -c -m moduleName file.f90
```

to convert it to a python module. It compiles without errors, and python can call it. But... Sadly, it returns nothing. I thought that using

```
!f2py intent(out,c) fMatrix
```

should change the memory-saving to the type python uses and return the fMatrix to python. But..

```
...
myf = fortranModule.f(args);
print myf
```

Returns "None".

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong; a few hits I did find mentioned something about the fact that fMatrix is N.3 and therefore it has trouble determining the return type?

I've tried adding the intent(in)/intent(out) to the fortran variable declarations, but that gave more errors in the start. However, I tried it again just now; the intent(in) declarations are working, but the intent(out) throws:

```
double precision, dimension(N, 3), intent(out):: fMatrix;                                                         
Error: Symbol at (1) is not a DUMMY variable
```

I hope someone has the answer for me,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I use is something as follows, i try to avoid the intent inout variable
because I find it sometimes confusing with call by reference thing
Instead I define a output variable in the subroutine itself and it automatically returns that

```
 subroutine f(fMatrix,oMatrix,N)
      implicit none; 
      integer,intent(in)::N
      double precision,intent(in),dimension(N, 3):: fMatrix
      double precision,intent(out),dimension(N, 3):: oMatrix
      !do stuff here with fMatrix
      !copy stuff to oMatrix using 
      oMatrix = fMatrix  
 end subroutine f
```

save as "test.f90" , compile it with

```
f2py --f90exec=gfortran  -DF2PY_REPORT_ON_ARRAY_COPY=1 --noarch
--f90flags='-march=native' -m test -c test.f90
```

test it with

```
In [6]: import test

In [7]: fmatrix = np.random.random((2,3))

In [8]: fmatrix Out[8]:  array([[ 0.19881303,  0.68857701, 
0.90133757],
       [ 0.92579141,  0.03823548,  0.98172467]])

In [9]: test.f(fmatrix) copied an array: size=6, elsize=8 Out[9]:  array([[ 0.19881303,  0.68857701,  0.90133757],
       [ 0.92579141,  0.03823548,  0.98172467]])
```

Comment: I've worked in C++ before, and used call by reference in PHP (&$bladievar) so I'm used to it. As for intent(inout), you need to add a !f2py intent(in,out) directive. Hadn't figured that one out! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hopeful at the moment; I think I fixed it. You need to have something like:

```
subroutine f(inputA, inputB, output)
```

and declare the output as intent(out). At least, when I did that it suddenly started printing matrices ;-)

So I checked the docstring:

```
Return objects:
    fmatrix : rank-2 array('d') with bounds (n,3)
```

Right!

Thanks, invisible people whom I'm talking to.

Comment: A second f2py subroutine confirms it; you need to put the output variables in the function parenthesis.